# How can I make Visual Studio 2013 resolve Node.js require() modules and provide intellisense?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I'm using Node.js 4.0.0 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 5. My code builds and runs just fine using Gulp, but I can't seem to get required modules to offer intellisense.

*My project is an ASP.NET Web Application.*

For example, I have a file as follows:

```
//constants/ActionTypes.js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    REQUEST_FILES: 'REQUEST_FILES',
    RECEIVE_FILES: 'RECEIVE_FILES'
};
```

I then import it into another file with `require`:

```
'use strict';

var ActionTypes = require('../constants/ActionTypes');

ActionTypes. <--- does not offer intellisense completion.
```

I've installed the following Visual Studio extensions which I thought would help with this:

- Node.js Tools 2.5
- WebEssentials 2013.5 2.6.36

I had already setup my project before installing the Node.js Tools, and didn't use the Node.js Tools templates. Is there some type of configuration that I need to do to my existing project?

How can I get intellisense to resolve my module exports?