# How can I write JavaScript modules such that VS Code (and other editors) provides intellisense?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, intellisense

I have used node.js modules that VS Code provided intellisense for. For example, I installed a library called `jsonfile` (via `npm install jsonfile --save`) and intellisense works like this:

```
const j = require('jsonfile');
j. // VS Code intellisense suggests all the methods with a brief description of parameters nad the method itself
```

Looking at the jsonfile code, I see:

```
var jsonfile = {
  spaces: null,
  readFile: readFile,
  readFileSync: readFileSync,
  writeFile: writeFile,
  writeFileSync: writeFileSync
}

module.exports = jsonfile
```

This is similar to my code, and I am not getting any intellisense:

***my-module.js***

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var x = "Hello I'm x"
    var y = function() {
        return "Hello I'm y"
    }
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
})()
```

***index.js***

```
const m = require('./my-module.js');
m. // No intellisense :(
```

***Question***

How do I structure my own modules so that VS Code will be able to provide basic intellisense for my own code? Is it something to do with installing via `npm`? Or is there an external file I need? Or something else...

This is actually similar to a question asked here: [How can I make Visual Studio 2013 resolve Node.js require() modules and provide intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173038/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-2013-resolve-node-js-require-modules-and-provide). But, alas, there is no answer. Also, VS Code may be different to VS in terms of intellisense implementation.

I'm also 100% sure this is possible, since the library `jsonfile` does exactly this.

Looking further into this, I found this documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript. Which seems to be instructions on how to achieve the above. I still think the question is relevant, however, since i'm fairly sure that a one paragraph response on how to achieve intellisense would make sifting through the documentation much, much easier.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here is a quick summary I came up with, going through the documentation.

> VS Code IntelliSense is provided for JavaScript, TypeScript, JSON,
>   HTML, CSS, Less, and Sass out of the box.[IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-for-your-programming-language)
>
> You can trigger IntelliSense in any editor window by typing Ctrl+Space
>   or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in
>   JavaScript).[Features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features)
>
> You can customize your IntelliSense experience in settings and key
>   bindings.[Customizing IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)
>
> If you find IntelliSense has stopped working, the language service may
>   not be running. Try restarting VS Code and this should solve the
>   issue.[Troubleshooting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_troubleshooting)

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: almost :). I'm not asking how intellisense works or how to use it. I'm asking how I can write modules that will work with intellisense. i.e. I want intellisense for my own code

Comment: What language specifically? Javascript? You can press  `ctrl + space` if it'snt working by default. That worked for me at least

Comment: I have no problem using intellisense with JavaScript thanks. Try reading the question again